# Extracting all string literals from a java project

Tags: java, string, localization, internationalization, translation

There is a big `Java` project that contains lots of `Java` and `JavaScript` classes. We need to translate the app into a foreign language.

What we need to do is:

1. Right click on a class
2. Click on `Extract Strings` button
3. Display all strings in the file with a check-list structure in a pop-up window
4. Select the strings we want to save
5. The unselected ones will be assigned as `not-string-literal` in order to prevent it from appearing in the list when I try next time.
6. Click on Ok and the strings are stored in a messages.properties file

We are using `Netbeans` IDE and a plugin would be wonderful if there is any. Can you advise me on how to do this?

Comment: The best fix here would be to introduce an i18n bundle into your Java application, which maintains translations for each string literal by language.  Then, your application may choose a certain language which will then do a lookup in the bundle.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Can you please elaborate more and give an example usage?

Comment: [The Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/index.html) is a good start.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But all those examples and tutorials include already generated `messages.properties` file. I'm trying to generate this file myself.

Comment: Then you may have to do some manual work at first.  Once you have i18n setup with the first bundle, adding support for any number of other languages should be relatively painless.

Comment: ***CAUTION:*** Replacing string literals is *not enough.*  For example, if you have an `int` variable named `x`, you would need to change `System.out.println(x);` to `System.out.println(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(x));`.  You also need to internationalize colors and images.  And of course, you will need to find all the places where strings intended to be displayed to the end user are being built, which likely won’t involve double-quotes much if at all.